# How to scroll through a (massive) pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, bigdata

Almost all my datasets are panel datasets. That is, I have a multi-index at the (say) Company and Time level.

Since I perform a lot of different operations, merges, etc, I want to know if there's a way to 'see' the data (like in excel) and scroll through my data quickly. That way I can spot if my code misses something or others.

What options are available for a large pandas dataframe (10GB+). I use a powerful desktop with 128GB RAM so I can easily fit the data into it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) library could be helpful. It is designed for such kind of tasks and developed and used by skilled quants. You should try it out. It is easy installed with pip:

```
pip install qgrid
```

Here is a [live demo](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/quantopian/qgrid/blob/master/qgrid_demo.ipynb) that allows you to do filtering, for example.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how i can load and see a pandas dataframe with it? Do you have a working example ?